# Separate Chaining: How many key comparisons do unsuccessful seaches take?

Tags: hash, hashtable

I can't find any clear information on how may key comparisons unsuccessful searches count (using linked lists for chaining).

Maybe someone can explain it to me with the help of the following example:

h(k)=k; m=4

0 || - | 
1 || 9 | 
2 || > | 6 | 10 | 
3 || > | 7 |

Let's say I search for 4, does it take 0 or 1 key comparisons to realise the value is not in the table?
If I searched for 14 how many key comparisons would that take? 2? 3?

Comment: How do you think it works?  "Let's say I search for 4" - can you work out which bucket that will hash to?  Given h(k) = k the hash value is 4, and if you take the remainder after dividing by the number of buckets (4), you get 0 - so bucket 0.  In there, there are currently no entries, so it's clear that the value 4 is not currently in the table.  How then would you try to answer your own question for 14?  What are you not sure about?

Comment: Yes, I understand how hashing works, however my question is how many key comparison operations are necessary for those unsuccessful searches.
You could implement a function that checks if the index is empty before comparing the key with null. So it could take either 0 or 1 key comparison operations to search for 4.
What's common practice?

Comment: The common practice for separate chaining implementations of hash tables is to have some kind of `struct Node { key_type k_; Node* p_next; }` structure for the links, and a `Node*` in the bucket.  If the bucket contains a `nullptr` then you don't even have a `Node` structure to look at, so there's no key object to compare anything to.  Similarly, if there's one Node containing say 6 as a key, with the `Node*` nullptr, then only one key comparison can be done.  It's common to think in terms of key comparisons while ignoring pointer/nullptr comparisons as the former can be arbitrarily expensive.